# Function with translation property

Tags: argument-patterns

I want to define a function `Υ[b, x]` of two arguments that has some special properties when there is a `b` in the second position:

```
Υ[b_, x_ + b_] := b^(1 - 2 b x) γ[b x] Υ[b, x]
Υ[b_, x_ + 1/b_] := b^(2 x/b - 1) γ[x/b] Υ[b, x]
```

This works fine as long as the argument is `x + b`, but this does not work for `Υ[b, x + 2 b]`, or `Υ[b, b]`, but note that it does work for `Υ[b, x + b + 1/b]`. I think the problem comes from the fact that *Mathematica* considers that `x_` cannot contain `b`. I have tried several other solutions, such as replacing `x_` by `f_[x_, b_]`, but I could not get anything to work. How can I modify my definition to get the correct behaviour?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: What is the expected result when `Υ[b, b]` is called? There will be no `x` for the `Υ[b, x]` in the function.

Comment: The expected answer is to use the above formula for x = 0, so the result would be `b γ(0) Υ(b, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, because it seems strange to me that when `Υ[b, x + c b]` is given, the coefficient `c` will ignored on the right-hand side of the definition. However, you can write the definition as

```
 Υ[b_, x_. + b_ c_.] := b^(1 - 2 b x) γ[b x] Υ[b, x]
```

and then

```
 Υ[b, b]
```

> `b γ[0] Υ[b, 0]`

and

```
 Υ[b, x + c b]
```

> `b^(1 - 2 b x) γ[b x] Υ[b, x]`

See the documentation article [Optional and Default Arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot and almost everything works fine.Now the only problem is that I have a substitution rule for taking a special limit (for small b), but this gives me an infinite recursion: `ΥAsym = Υ[b_, b_ x_] -> Υ[b, b] b^(1 - x) Gamma[x]};`. In the worst case I can fix it by keeping the value Υ(b, b) like this (by deleting the dot in x_.), but I was wondering if you had another idea?

Comment: The same problem appeared in other circumstances and is due to the fact that Mathematica will write `b x = b (x - 1 + 1)`, and after the translation the parenthesis will be rewritten to `b (x - 2)`, and so on. The way I found to fix is by adding a condition on c: `Υ[b_, x_. + n_. b_ /; n ∈ Integers] := 
  With[{xx = x + (n - 1) b}, 
   b^(1 - 2 b xx) γ[b xx] Υ[b, xx]];`

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
Y[b_, x_ + c_] := 
  If[c == b || c == 1/b, b^(1 - 2 b x) γ[b x] Y[b, x], None]
```

??

Comment: This does not work, here is the output for Υ[b, x + 2 b]: `If[b == 0, b^(1 - 2 b x) \[Gamma][b x] Y[b, x], None]`.
P.S. : I have edited my original post, I made a mistake when writing the second relation (the two RHS are different), but this does not change the problem.

Comment: OK, but you can account for all this yourself.

Comment: For the second yes, this is just the same kind (I was mostly giving it to be comprehensive). But still using your formula I cannot get was I want: Υ(b, b) is not simplified, while for Υ(b, x + 2b) this does not give the expected result, and I don't see how to modify your code to get it.